# Issue with if statement with templates in Underscore.js

Tags: underscore.js

Here is my template:

```php
<script type="text/html" id="template_medassign">        
    <div class=" <%= pocket.get('spanTag') %>" >
        <a data-toggle="modal" href="#windowTitleDialog" class="thumbnail">                
            <% if ( <%= pocket.get('drugDoseDisplayName') %>.length < 0   ) { %>
                <label ><%= pocket.get('drugDoseDisplayName') %></label>
            <% } else { %>
                ...else block
            <% } %>
        </a>
    </div>
</script>
```

I am passing `pocket` object data from main template, and able to retrieve data for `spanTag` and `drugDoseDisplayName` properties.  But if I try with in a if statement I am getting error from underscore.js with "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Expected ')'"

I tried other way as well, by maintaining another prop in model with bool flag, but no luck. Pl suggest the solution.

```php
<% if ( <%= pocket.get('isMedAsiigned') %>   ) { %>
<% if ( %> <%= pocket.get('isMedAsiigned') %> <%  ) { %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to nest your template tags:

```
<% if ( <%= pocket.get('drugDoseDisplayName') %>.length < 0   ) { %>
        ^^^                                   ^^
```

and that is producing invalid JavaScript when `_.template` compiles your template into a JavaScript function. Once you're inside `<% ... %>`, you're already in JavaScript, from the [fine manual](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template):

> [...] as well as execute arbitrary JavaScript code, with <% … %>

There's no need to nest you template tags, you can just do this:

```
<% if ( pocket.get('drugDoseDisplayName').length < 0 ) { %>
```